# AWS lambda URL request and write binary to /tmp/

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I'm using API gateway + lambda function integration and Python 3.8. I need to recieve a post from an external webhook. The webhook sends a JSON object with some data and a url. I'm trying to use requests lib to get a pdf file from the url and write in /tmp/ dir. I already have uploaded requests lib into lambda from a zip and works fine. I'm further planning to upload the pdf into S3.

The problem: the requested file from URL are not being writen to /tmp/ dir.

- No error messages.
- Not a heavy file (<10 mb).

```py
import json
import requests
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    prods = event
    body = json.loads(prods["body"])
    url = body["url"]

    print("Body:", body)

    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.content

    with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
        fd.write(content)

    print(os.listdir("/tmp/"))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': {
            'file_path': '/tmp/test.pdf'
        }
    }
```

I already tryied to chunk the file using the following strategy:

```py
url = 'http://www.example.com'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

with open('/tmp/test.pdf', 'wb') as fd:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        fd.write(chunk)
```

Edit: seems to be a 'time out' question. Saw this on CloudWatch:
**Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: seems to be a 'time out' question. Saw this on CloudWatch: **Task timed out after 3.00 seconds**

According to the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/):

> **Q: How long can an AWS Lambda function execute?**
>
> AWS Lambda functions can be configured to run up to 15 minutes per execution. You can set the timeout to any value between 1 second and 15 minutes.

So visit the configuration page of your Lambda, and increase the time limit.